# How to access an event handler function from another module?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, event-handling

I am trying to make an application in which I have a button which when clicked will call a function. I want to put that function in another module than the main module. I placed the function in another module and imported it into the main module but I don't know how to bind it.

Basically, I want to know that how to access a function defined in a module by a widget that is defined in another main module. For example, in the given code the button is defined in the main module but the event handler function is defined in another module. Now I want to know that how can I access that function process_event.

**MainModule.py**

```
my_button = tk.Button(application_window, text="Example")
my_button.bind("<Enter>", process_event)
```

**AmotherModule.py**

```
def process_event(event):
       print("The process_event function was called.")
```

Comment: `import AmotherModule` and `bind(..., AmotherModule.process_event)`

Answer (score 1):

**MainModule.py**

```
import AmotherModule 

my_button.bind("<Enter>", AmotherModule.process_event)
```

or

```
import AmotherModule as am

my_button.bind("<Enter>", am.process_event)
```

or

```
from AmotherModule import process_event

my_button.bind("<Enter>", process_event)
```